# Paramiko with continuous stdout

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I use Paramiko to run some ssh commands to the remote Linux server. The commands will have continuous output in the console and I want to print these all information in the local console window.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.client.exec_command("ls")
for line in stdout.read()
    print line,
ssh.client.close()
```

So if I write the code like this, all the output information will be sent back to me until the command finishes executing while I want to print the output in live.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course there is a way to do this. Paramiko `exec_command` is async, buffers are filled while data arrives regardless of your main thread.

In your example `stdout.read(size=None)` will try to read the full buffer size at once. Since new data is always arriving, it won't ever exit. To avoid this, you could just try to read from `stdout` in smaller chunks. Here's an example that reads buffers bytewise and yields lines once a `\n` is received.

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("while true; do uptime; done")

def line_buffered(f):
    line_buf = ""
    while not f.channel.exit_status_ready():
        line_buf += f.read(1)
        if line_buf.endswith('\n'):
            yield line_buf
            line_buf = ''

for l in line_buffered(stdout):
    print l
```

You can increase performance by tweaking the code to use `select.select()` and by having bigger chunk sizes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758464/1729555) that also takes into account common hang and remote command exit detection scenarios that may lead to empty responses.

Comment: The answer is good. But you also need to cater for the `stderr`, otherwise the code might deadlock. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

Comment: Btw, wouldn't this simple code do? `while True:` `line = f.readline()` `if len(line) == 0:` `break` `print(line)` Or even simple `for line in stdout:` `print(line)`

Comment: For python3 I had to make all strings byte-strings `b""` and then `.decode("utf-8")` while printing. If someone would elaborate on increasing the performance I would be glad

Comment: this answer did not solve the problem in my case, I had to use this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642555/real-time-output-for-paramiko-exec-command

Answer (score -1):

So because sharing is caring , I resolved the issue for the PARAMIKO with continuous output like this (ignore the index and replace stuff, issues proprietary to my device):

```
"elif action == "icmd":
        cmd = command
        channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
        channel.exec_command(cmd)
        channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
        index = 0
        a = ""  # list to be filled with output of the commands.
        while True:
            if channel.exit_status_ready():
                break
            o = channel.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")
            if o:
                a += o
                if "\n" in o:
                    b = a.split("\n")
                    a = b[-1]
                    b.pop()
                    for x in b:
                        print(x.replace("●", "").replace("└─", ""), flush=True)
                        index += 1
                if index == 0 and len(o) > 0:
                    print(o.replace("●", "").replace("└─", ""), flush=True)
                if index == 0 and len(o) == 0:
                    print(f"Your command '{cmd}' did not returned anything! ")
        channel.close()
        ssh.close()
```

"

I chose the split and pop things because when using commands like : traceroute [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) , for example, the output was splited into separate rows.

Also, I integrated a shell, for interactive input/output with the device, like this :

```
elif action == "shell":
        channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
        cmd = command
        print("Shell started")
        print(channel.recv(2048).decode())
        while True:
            if channel.exit_status_ready():
                print("Session Ended!")
                break
            try:
                cmd = input(cmd)
                channel.send(f"{cmd}\n".encode())
                time.sleep(1)
                output = channel.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")
                print(output.replace("●", "").replace("└─", ""), flush=True)
                if cmd == "exit":
                    break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
        channel.close()
        ssh.close()
```

Enjoy it !