# Get output of Python remotely in realtime

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have this simple python code:

```
import time

print "1"
time.sleep(3)
print "2"
time.sleep(2)
```

And then I use paramiko to run it remotely:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('X.X.X.X', username='user', key_filename='/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/user/test.py')
print stdout.read()

ssh.close()
```

It will wait until the Python code finishes and then print everything. But I want it to print each line in real-time. How can I do it?

Thank you.

**Update**: I tried to run the Python code by ssh command:

```
ssh user@X.X.X.X "python /home/user/test.py"
```

And the output is the same. It waits until Python code finish and then prints out everything. 
If I run a shell script remotely, both ssh command and paramiko are fine.

Comment: Here is the similar question with an answer: [paramiko with continuous stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260088/paramiko-with-continuous-stdout)

Comment: I read and followed it but no difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `-u` to `python` to get [unbuffered stdout](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) and iterate over your `stdout` to get each line:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python -u /home/user/test.py')
for line in stdout:
    print line.rstrip()
```

Comment: Amazing ! It works now ! Thank you so much. You save my night