# Real-time output for Paramiko exec_command

Tags: python, docker, paramiko

**NOTE**: I have seen other posts on this, but not a single post can explain the answer, nor do they have one that works.

Is there a way to get the output of `exec_command`, specifically for `exec_command('docker run <CONTAINER_ID>')` in real-time for the Paramiko package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may read lines from `ChannelFile` (http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/channel.html?highlight=stdout#paramiko.channel.ChannelFile).

Example:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('docker run <CONTAINER_ID>')
while True:
    line = stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Nice!...... bor.

Comment: When using this I noticed it is as if my shell script runs async, even though I'm using `;` between commands. Is this maybe a side effect of `readline()` method?