# Paramiko recv()/read()/readline(s)() on stderr returns empty string

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, stderr

I'm using paramiko to collect some information on a remote host and experience issues, when reading (`read()`/`readline()`/`readlines()`) from the `stderr` channel.

Sometimes `stderr.read()` returns an empty string which to me looks like a result of a race condition.
However, according to documentation and examples I found on the internet, this seems the exact way to go.

I also tried to open a dedicated channel and make use of `chan.recv_ready()` / `chan.recv_stderr_ready()` and reading from respective channels in a loop via `chan.recv()` / `chan.recv_stderr()` which however results in the same behaviour.

Here's a minimal test case which - in my setup - reliably causes that behaviour.

```
import paramiko

class SSH:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', port=31337, username='root', password='root')

        self.stdout = ''
        self.stderr = ''
        self.exit_code = 0

    def _run_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.stdout = ''
        self.stderr = ''

        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)

        self.stdout = stdout.read()
        self.stderr = stderr.read()

        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            pass
        self.exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()

        if self.exit_code:
            print("ERROR: " + self.stderr)

    def process_list(self):
        self._run_cmd('ls /proc/ | grep -E "^[0-9]+$" | grep -v $$')
        lines = self.stdout.split('\n')[:-1]
        data = []

        for process in lines:
            process_data = {}
            process_data['pid'] = int(process)

            # fetching and parsing process status information from /proc/[PID]/status

            self._run_cmd('cat /proc/%d/status' % (int(process)))

            data.append(self.stdout)

        return data


data = SSH()
while True:
    print data.process_list()
```

What I get after a couple of runs (if not the first one already) is:

`ERROR:`

while I am expecting:

`ERROR: cat: /proc/12883/status: No such file or directory`

How can I make sure stderr is ready to read from / I read all data on stderr?

Answer (score 1):

**long story short**: I've run into most of these problems and came up with my ultimate solution to most of my ssh related problems. Therefore feel free to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758464/1729555) implementation of `exec_command` avoiding most of the empty_response/stalling scenarios.

**long story**

The main problem here is that you `exec_command()` is non-blocking and spawns a thread that takes care of the channels communication. This thread is waiting for incoming data and puts it into the channels buffers while the main thread may go on. This is where your problem lies. You're reading your buffers too early, even before you checked that your side received the `exit_status`. Receiving the `exit_status` confirms that the remote process exited with the given status code. Receiving the remote status code is **not** an indication that you've received all the data that may still be in transit. It may even arrive out-of-order at your side, saying that the `status_code` may arrive even before all the data (`stderr`,`stdout`) was received.

While data is arriving, the main thread continues. In your case, the main thread tries to read from `stdout` and `stderr` once and then blocks until the `exit_status` is ready. Note that the channel thread may still receive data from your remote command invocation. Also note that you'll have to manually empty buffers once your side received the remote `exit_status`.

In your specific case this is what happens:

1. `execute_command` spawns a new thread (lets call id **exec_thread**, managing the remote command invocation
2. while data may be received by the recently spawned thread, the main thread goes on.
3. [main-thread] you're storing the **current** contents of the `stdout`,`stderr` buffers in `self.stdout`,`self.stderr`. Note that you do not know if you've received all of the data of `stderr` or `stdout`. Most likely you've just received a few chunks.
4. [exec_thread] happily receives data for `stdout`,`stderr` while [main-thread] goes on.
5. [main-thread] busy-blocks until the `exit_status` is received. Again note, that at this point your buffers may still be full with recently received `stderr`,`stdout` chunks.
6. [main-thread] the `exit_status` is stored in `self.exit_code`. [exec_thread] is still alive, may still receive some out of order data. input buffers might still be filled.
7. [main-thread] returns from `run_cmd`

Note that [exec_thread] for that channel - paramiko creates one thread per channel invocation (i.e. `exec_command`) - is still alive and they'll sum up idling around and creating problems until you manually close them (`stdout.channel.close()`).